# Add anchor text to php

Tags: title, wp-list-pages

I am using this code to display a list of child pages of a parent:

```
<?php
global $post; // Setup the global variable $post
if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
    // Make sure we are on a page and that the page is a parent.
    $kiddies = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );  
} else {
    $kiddies = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );
}

if ( $kiddies ) {
    echo '<ul class="secondary">';
        echo $kiddies;
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

I want to be able to customise the anchor text of the link. e.g. if the child page name is "blue" I want to append "widget" to the end to make the anchor "blue widget".

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`the_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) filter. Just remember to remove it after `wp_list_pages()` otherwise it will effect everywhere on the site like in menu, main title, search results etc.

Example:-

```
add_filter('the_title', 'my_custom_title');
wp_list_pages();
remove_filter('the_title', 'my_custom_title');

function my_custom_title($current_title) {
    if ($current_title == 'blue') {
        $current_title = $current_title . ' widget';
    }

    return $current_title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sumit. If I wanted to add the same string to all anchors how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Then just remove the condition `if ($current_title == 'blue') {`